Python function : return array that was named automatically
My final goal is to recover data from a table, and store it in numpy arrays to work with it later.
I had to automatically name each columns of my dataframe (I've opened my file using pandas) due to my application. (I want it to work with other files as well, for example if the columns order is not the same each time)
I made this loop (with help of internet) :
noms_cols = fichier_elevation[0].columns.tolist() # create a list with the columns names

#Create numpy table for each column with automatically assigned name
namespace = globals() 
for noms in set(noms_cols): 
    if noms=='hour':
        #np array creation and 4-line header removal
        namespace['%s' % noms] = pd.to_datetime(fichier_elevation[0].loc[4:,'hour'], 
                                                errors='coerce',            format='mixed').reset_index(drop=True) #reset the index
                              
    else :
        namespace['%s' % noms] = pd.to_numeric(fichier_elevation[0].loc[4:,noms], 
                                               errors='coerce', downcast='float').reset_index(drop=True)

It creates as many arrays as there are columns in the file (=as there are series in the dataframe)
(I'm just not sure how globals() works..)
To be clean (and curiosity), I'm trying to create a function that will return these numpy arrays (that has been created and named automatically).
The problem is, I can't just do  return MyArray1, MyArray2, etc...  at the end of the function, since theoretically I don't know there names (or rather I can't list them since there can be little variation from a file to another)
In short, I just want to return my arrays (automatically named) without naming them explicitly
I've done some research but didn't found anything interesting about it except for the use of a **list **or a dictionnary, but it seems unpertinent to work with dictionary since I have dataframe at first. I wonder if there is an 'elegant' way of doing it.
I know also that I could just not create numpy array and work directly with pandas series but since I have a 4-line header and a little handling to do on data (and don't really want to modify the dataframe), it seems the better idea.
I hope my problem (and english) will be understandable.
Thank you for your help.

You cannot dynamically assign variables.  Use a dictionary instead.

Dictionaries are waaaaay more elegant than modifying globals with dynamically named variables. Don't do that.
